# SoundTouch compilation with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, soundtouch

I'm trying to compile SoundTouch Framework in my Xcode project,
but I have no clue of what I'm doing to be honest.

Does anyone have any instructions?

**What I've done so far**

Running `./bootstrap` gives me the following output

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I config/m4 --output=aclocal.m4t
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

If I recall correctly, there is no `autoreconf` for Mac OS, right?

SoundTouch apparently requires at least `GCC 4.4` but Mac OS only has `GCC 4.3`, so I downloaded `GCC 7` from `homebrew`, but using it only with the command `gcc-7 ./bootstrap` gives me the following output

```
gcc-7 bootstrap
ld: warning: ignoring file bootstrap, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x23 0x20 0x24 0x49 0x64 0x3A 0x20 0x62 0x6F 0x6F 0x74 0x73 0x74 0x72 0x61 0x70 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): bootstrap
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I successfully compile SoundTouch?

**EDIT:**

I tried copying the essential files to one folder, add it to my project and compile.

Now I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "soundtouch::SoundTouch::SoundTouch()", referenced from:
      MyAudioProcessor::MyAudioProcessor() in libMy.a(PluginProcessor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is it saying that there are undefined symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the essential files of SoundTouch to the project's "Compile Sources" definition.

Now it compiles.

[image]

Comment: Do you create a bridging header for importing the .h files ? If not, how did you use Sound touch function by only add it on compile sources?

Comment: No bridging header. I don't understand exactly what it is that you're asking me.